# How to flush right some text in a align* environment?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align

In the following MWE, I would to flush right the words "car a⊥b et par linéarité".

Is it possible?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\mathopen{}\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert\mathclose{}}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Gamma(a+b, c) &=
\begin{vmatrix}
\norm{a+b}^2 & \braket{a+b, c} \\
\braket{a+b, c} & \norm{c}^2
\end{vmatrix} \\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
\norm{a}^2+\norm{b}^2 & \braket{a, c} +  \braket{b, c} \\
\braket{a, c} +\braket{b, c} & \norm{c}^2
\end{vmatrix} \hspace{1cm}\text{car $a\perp b$ et par linéarité}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `\tag*` from the `amsmath` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\mathopen{}\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert\mathclose{}}


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Gamma(a+b, c) &=
\begin{vmatrix}
\norm{a+b}^2 & \braket{a+b, c} \\
\braket{a+b, c} & \norm{c}^2
\end{vmatrix} \\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
\norm{a}^2+\norm{b}^2 & \braket{a, c} +  \braket{b, c} \\
\braket{a, c} +\braket{b, c} & \norm{c}^2
\end{vmatrix}  \tag*{car $a\perp b$ et par linéarité}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: That's so neat! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I see no reason for pushing the comment to the margin. If you really want it, I'd prefer to (ab)use `flalign` rather than `\tag`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{showframe}

%\newcommand{\norm}[1]{\mathopen{}\left\lVert #1 \right\rVert\mathclose{}}% <- wrong
\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm}{\lVert}{\rVert}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Gamma(a+b, c) &=
\begin{vmatrix}
\norm{a+b}^2 & \braket{a+b, c} \\
\braket{a+b, c} & \norm{c}^2
\end{vmatrix} \\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
\norm{a}^2+\norm{b}^2 & \braket{a, c} +  \braket{b, c} \\
\braket{a, c} +\braket{b, c} & \norm{c}^2
\end{vmatrix}
&\text{car $a\perp b$ et par linéarité}
\end{align*}

\begin{flalign*}
&&
\Gamma(a+b, c) &=
\begin{vmatrix}
\norm{a+b}^2 & \braket{a+b, c} \\
\braket{a+b, c} & \norm{c}^2
\end{vmatrix} \\
&&
&= \begin{vmatrix}
\norm{a}^2+\norm{b}^2 & \braket{a, c} +  \braket{b, c} \\
\braket{a, c} +\braket{b, c} & \norm{c}^2
\end{vmatrix}
&\text{car $a\perp b$ et par linéarité}
\end{flalign*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Why is your definition of `\norm` wrong? Try your definition with `\norm{\dfrac{1}{2}v}_2` (for the Euclidean norm) and mine with `\norm*{\dfrac{1}{2}v}_2`:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment about \norm !

Answer (score 2):

You can have the equation centred, together with text flushright, with the `linegoal` package, which measures the remaining space at the current point (two compilations required):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{linegoal} 
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{braket}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.3pt}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter{\norm} \lVert \rVert


\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\Gamma(a+b, c) &=
\begin{vmatrix}
\norm{a+b}^2 & \braket{a+b, c} \\
\braket{a+b, c} & \norm{c}^2
\end{vmatrix} \\
&= \begin{vmatrix}
\norm{a}^2+\norm{b}^2 & \braket{a, c} + \braket{b, c} \\
\braket{a, c} +\braket{b, c} & \norm{c}^2
\end{vmatrix} \rlap{\parbox{\linegoal}{\raggedleft car $a\perp b$ et par linéarité}}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]